# MS SQL Server 2008 - Finding Max value from a subset of results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to pull out the most recent order and the price tagged to that item in a report. I would like to pull the max value (most recent record) that are of type P for all different parts in the system.

```
part | type | orderno | price |
-------------------------------
 aj1    p     1332       200
 aj1    v     2013       10
 aj1    v     2013       15

SELECT *
FROM od
WHERE type='P'' 
and od.orderno = (select max(orderno) from od i where i.partno=od.partno)
```

My results are coming out empty. When I take out the type restriction, I get the 2 V orders which is not what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add `and type=od.type` to the subquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM od
WHERE orderno IN(SELECT MAX(orderno), Part FROM od WHERE Type = 'P' GROUP BY Part)
```

Edit: I can't spell.

Answer (score 1):

As JNK stated, your subquery isn't looking at the same criteria that your outer WHERE clause is.  Your query `select max(orderno) from od i where i.partno=od.partno` should return `2013` from your example data.  Thus your WHERE clause is really `WHERE type='P'' and od.orderno = 2013` and of course that doesn't match any rows.

Comment: Thanks for providing a background on what I was doing wrong!!